# Auth0 Callback URL mismatch Python FastAPI

Tags: python, callback, aws-api-gateway, auth0, amazon-route53

I'm currently having trouble with a web app (Python FastAPI that serves up Jinja Templates) that I am trying to use auth0 in for user authentication. The app is deployed using an AWS Lambda, API Gateway, and Route 53.

It works perfectly locally, however, when trying to access the deployed application, I am receiving this error
[image: Auth0 redirect error]

In my auth0 application, under the Callback URIs section, I have added a couple of URLs. I added "http://localhost:8000/callback" which is the url that works locally.

I tried adding the url that corresponds with my Route53 record: something like "https://route.dev.zone.com/callback" and this didn't work.

Has anyone else faced an issue similar to this, where auth0 redirects would work fine locally, but fail in a deployed application?

Edit: I doubt that it's a problem with the code, but I could be wrong about that. Here is my relevant login code:

```py
oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name='auth0',
    client_id=auth0.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret=auth0.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    server_metadata_url=f'https://{auth0.get("AUTH0_DOMAIN")}/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid profile email'}
)
```

```py
@app.get('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    auth0 = oauth.create_client('auth0')
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('callback')
    return await auth0.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)
```

```py
@app.get('/callback')
async def callback(request: Request):
auth0 = oauth.create_client('auth0')
    token = await auth0.authorize_access_token(request)
    request.session['userinfo'] = token.get('userinfo')
    return RedirectResponse("/")
```

Comment: The problem is easy to solve once you have the correct information. Research the following: a) what is the Client ID your app is using? b) what is the list of redirect URIs that you configured for that Client ID? c) what is the URI that your app is using? d) once you have that information is the URI your app is using on the list of authorized redirect URIs? If not, you know the problem. If yes, you made a mistake in what you think you configured.

Comment: If you click on the "See the details for this error" link in the bottom left, you'll see what redirect URI you're sending.

Comment: @MattRaible Ahh thank you for pointing that out. I completely missed that